# Replace text from the middle of the string

Tags: php, mysql

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
     <th>filepath</th>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
     <th>uploads/1233/a.jpg</th>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2</th>
     <th>uploads/1213/b.jpg</th>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>3</th>
     <th>uploads/1243/c.jpg</th>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>4</th>
     <th>uploads/1234/d.jpg</th>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>5</th>
     <th>uploads/1273/e.jpg</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

`id` and `filepath` are coming from a mysql table.
I want to replace the numeric value between the uploads folder and the image name.

How do I do this in mysql or in php?

Comment: Please describe your requirement proper. _I want to after uploads folder and before the image file_? Is there a sense?

Comment: [This might help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9261713/regex-strip-out-text-between-first-and-second-forward-slashes)

Comment: this is full path uploads/1273/e.jpg??? and u want to remove numeric value?? correct me...

Comment: Have a look at SUBSTRING_INDEX in the manual, it will likely be what you need.

Comment: Yes it is full path and  I want to remove numeric value.

Comment: your url is fixed??? only this .. uploads/1273/e.jpg

Comment: Can you please be clear with your question ? Do you want to replace 1273 in uploads/1273/e.jpg ?

Comment: I want to remove numeric value and I want just like this uploads/a.jpg

Answer (score 1):

try this example :

```
<?php
$str = "uploads/1234/d.jpg";
$strArray = explode("/", $str);
$strOutput = $strArray[0]."/".$strArray[2];
echo $strOutput;
?>
```

In mysql, you can try something like this :

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION customise_str(str_input varchar) RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE COUNT INT DEFAULT 9;

  WHILE COUNT > 0 DO
SET str_input = REPLACE(str_input, COUNT, "");
    SET COUNT = COUNT - 1;
  END WHILE;

RETURN (str_input);
END  $$
DELIMITER ;;


update table_name set fielname = customise_str(fielname);
```

I have not tried this code.

if you do not know how to create stored functions, these links may be helpful for you :

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-function/

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/while.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Is there any way to remove all numeric value from a mysql table field and the type of values in the field are "uploads/1235/a.jpg","uploads/1270/b.jpg" and so on but I want to remove numeric value from the field value such as "uploads/a.jpg","uploads/b.jpg" and so on.

Comment: I have updated my answer. For this you need to define your own function in mysql.

Comment: Sir I tried your code and getting  MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') RETURNS VARCHAR(300)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE COUNT INT DEFAULT 9;' at line 1

Comment: I am trying by this code but it is incorrect anyone can correct it ."update `tableName` set filepath=replace(filepath) where filepath like %/[1-9999]/%"

Answer (score 1):

Try this preg_replace function PHP.

```
$filepath = "uploads/1233/a.jpg";
echo preg_replace('/(?<=\/)[1-9][0-9]*?(?=\/)/', "replacement_string_for_the_numeric_value", $filepath);
```