# Python: return a string between // regex

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I still do not understand regex. I read the docs, but after I came up with the regex character, then how to use them?

For example, I want to return only whatever between the first two slashes

```
en/lemon_peel/n/,
ca/llimona/n/,
```

the output for is should be: lemon_peel and llimona

I tried on regex tester something like this: `([^/]*)` but never worked

Comment: why not use split instead of regex

Comment: Instead of a regex how about `your_line.split('/')[1]`?

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks, it worked!!

Comment: Technically, it's not a dup, since its title mentions regex. Anyway, I couldn't add my answer here, so I added it to the other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use regex you should use regex like this:

```
import re

tmp_string = '''
    en/lemon_peel/n/,
    ca/llimona/n/,
    '''

reg = re.search('/([^/,]*)/',tmp_string)
result = reg.group(1)
```

In your case you find all of symbols that are not '/'.

Or you can use `split` function instead of `re`:

```
tmp_string.split('/')[1]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I mean now where to put these characters? inside a split() function or where ?

Comment: I edit my answer, for regular expression you should use `re` module in python

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutelly want to use regular expression, you can use the following:

```
import re
pattern = r'\w[^/]*'
results = re.findall(pattern, "en/lemon_peel/n/")
```

Value of `results` is the list:

```
['en', 'lemon_peel', 'n']
```